# Symfony2 LiipImagineBundle path cache probleme

Tags: php, symfony, liipimaginebundle

I've setup a LiipImagineBundle configuration on a linux computer (xubuntu 14.10) :

routing.yml

```
_liip_imagine:
    resource: "@LiipImagineBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml"
```

config.yml

```
liip_imagine:
    resolvers:
       default:
          web_path: ~

    filter_sets:
        cache: ~
        dashboard_thumb:
            quality: 75
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [60, 60], mode: outbound }
```

and in my twig template :

```
<img src="{{ asset(company.logo.getPath) | imagine_filter('dashboard_thumb') }}">
```

All sources images are under **web/uploads** path
This was working fine, image thumbnails are generated under **web/media/cache/dashboard_thumb/uploads/**

My source files are stored under an USB stick, and i lanch server with server:run commande (so under 127.0.0.1:8000)

But recently, i lanched the server under another computer (linux mint 17) and then, image cache are not generated anymore.

when i look at the generated html source, file path for images are :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/cache/resolve/dashboard_thumb/uploads/myimage.png
```

so i dont know why there is a 'resolve' in the path

Other thing, if i launch the command :

```
liip:imagine:cache:resolve uploads/myimage.png
```

the path and image web/media/cache/dashboard_thumb/uploads/myimage.png are well created

why this doesnt work automatically?

Thanks.

Comment: check the user permission on the linux (apache user vs cli user)

Comment: hi, thanks for answer, when i check permissions on web/media/cache, i've got : **drwxrwxrwx 1 myname root 0 janv. 31 15:11 web/media/cache/**, how can i set apache as owner of this path (i'm new to linux world)?

Comment: as temporary workaround you can set all permission to all user to che cache folder with `chmod -R  777 web/media/cache`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem a problem about Setting up Permissions. Basically the System operating users for the CLI(and deploy) and the web server must be on the same group.

Check the doc for [Symfony Application Configuration and Setup](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup)

PS: the command you are looking for is chown but is only a workaround an i suggest you to fix to operating user layer.

Hope this help

Comment: Hi, i'm trying the 1st method (since chmod +a seems not available for mint) but when i check my apache2.conf, User and Group value are set to "www-data", so normally apache can access my folders and files no?

Comment: Ok, my bad, i've trying a service apache2 restart, but i've forget to restart  symfony server (stop and relaunch server:run command). So, now it seems working flawlessly :). Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

> ... so i dont know why there is a 'resolve' in the path

If You do not have a cache for your image, `LiipImagineBundle` (`imagine_filter` in your case) generates a route according this rule

```
liip_imagine_filter:
    path: /media/cache/resolve/{filter}/{path}
    defaults:
        _controller: '%liip_imagine.controller.filter_action%'
    methods:
        - GET
    requirements:
        filter: '[A-z0-9_-]*'
        path: .+
```

, and your request handles by `ImagineController`  https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle/blob/1.0/Controller/ImagineController.php

So, You see not image path, but route. Controller generates the cache and your second request to this image will give you actually path to image.

There is a problem, if your need to attach image to mail message, You have to resolve image before attaching this one.

Also if cache not generates anymore, the problem maybe in your web server configuration. Imagine that Your Nginx decides that web/media/cache/*   is static content, so, the route web/media/cache/resolve just not working.